# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS + Wacom Volito tablet drivers settings (Linux/Unix/MacOs)

Tags: linux, macos, drivers

I connected very old tablet Wacom Volito to the Ubuntu 20.04 and it behaves correctly as tablet, out of the box (no additional drivers installed). Connected to macOS Big Sur it behaves as mouse.

Where I can find the settings or preinstalled drivers in Linux or macOS for tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Wacom needs drivers for Mac. The Volito's basic design [read cheap & cheerful compared to the majority of Wacoms] means it nominally interacts as an HID device, a mouse, so a pen will not work 'out of the box'.

Wacom never made drivers for OS X [well, they did but they were so buggy they retracted them]
'Word on the street' is that the Intuos/Graphire drivers would work at one time, but without a functional control panel.

…however…

I very much doubt when that idea was circulating that anyone considered how long the old Intuos/Graphire support would last. It lasted until El Capitan & after that there were ways of forcing it into later macOS.
That ended with Catalina, which will not run 32-bit software at all.

I think that's the end of the road for your venerable Volito.

I still have an Intuos II that I've managed to keep going up to Mojave, but that's it. No way to get it going on any later OS.

Refs I found on my journey…
https://www.thinkyhead.com/tabletmagic/ - a macOS driver for 'older Wacoms' - as it was last updated 2013 I think the chances are slim that it will work in Catalina or later. Might be worth a try.  ***Edit:** Forget that - it's for older serial port tablets only*
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040610095835241 - last updated a decade ago.

Comment: Thank you 
I was hoping that I can just update some configuration files from Terminal but looks like this is one of the levels where Unix Linux MacOs differ 
Good thing is that I can still use it as a fullscreen tablet plus pressure sensitive without additional drivers installed on Ubuntu in Blender 3D app.